# How to Get viewAtLocation:(CGPoint)location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiview

Now a days in several of my iOS applications I need to get adjacent views recursively. I wonder if we have any thing like `viewAtLocation:(CGPoint)location`? Or there's any way we can implement it.

I have used several ways like C array `id matrix[row][col]` with location decided by size as index value, and retrieving all `subview` then checking for `location` one by one in a loop etc. Although these are working for me but these doesn't seems good or say appropriate to me. So what else we can have?

Comment: Will you please elaborate more what do you mean by 'Adjacent views'?

Comment: @Mohit_Jaiswal Actually First line describe the situation, only that what i am dealing with. Still with adjacent I meant just next, previous, up and down. But it have not too much to do with question.

Comment: So, what I'm getting that in your visible view, you have more than one view and you need/intend to get the location of that views. Am I right? Well, if that case than I think it's not hard deal, let me make a lib first and will get back to you.

Comment: When would you need to get these views? When somebody touches it? When a button is pressed? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mohit_Jaiswal Thanks Buddy, wishing you luck.. :)

Comment: Really thanks for your best wishes.I'll try my best. Meanwhile, have a good night. :)

Comment: @Cubia Yeah you can take instance of any event, but I need a view at given location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to use the standard [`hitTest:withEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) which will handle things like ignoring a view if it's opacity is 0.0. The documentation says to pass in `nil` for the event when calling it manually.

This will also behave correctly for any views which have extended their bounds using `pointInside:withEvent:`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for but was there deep inside big documentation..

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do it for you bro

```
UIView *view = <Your View>;
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{

    CGPoint p = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    for (UIView *v in recognizer.view.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, p)) {
            NSLog(@"view Found with frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(v.frame));
            //If your views doesn't overlap then break from here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks dear but as i have mentioned, **"and retrieving all subview then checking for location one by one in a loop etc."** this i have already done and sure it works.. :) thus +1..

Comment: Well If you doesn't want loping then I'll prefer to use Custom UIButton with my intended design. Every button will have unique tag. and I can decide based on tag which button is tapped now.

Comment: check accepted answer.. :), we may have other many tasks for tag.. That we usually have.